# Debug mode not working on Visual studio mac preview

Tags: xamarin

I'm having a problem where i can't debug my Xamarin application onto my android device. The app is installed on my phone but when i start the application it immediately crashes.

please help me!

Comment: Does it work using Xamarin Studio (VS is a preview after all)? Anything in the application output?

Comment: Yeah it works with Xamarin Studio. But was hoping that VS worked. Guess il use Xamarin Studio.

Comment: I've seen VS break the ABI list sometimes, so check all the ABIs you need are being built